# What are the task of Job Scheduling and VM Scheduling in cloud computing?

Tags: cloud, scheduling

I am new to cloud computing and may be my question not appropriate here, but I want to know that, are Job Scheduling and VM Scheduling are same process? And one another thing is what are the disadvantages of WRR (Weighted Round Robin) algorithm in VM Scheduling?

Comment: To understand the disadvantages of WRR, look at [these slides](http://www.optaplanner.org/learn/slides/optaplanner-presentation/index.html#/16) and click right to go the next slide. Simply explanation: it's suboptimal. In my benchmarks I see a quality loss of 9% versus more advanced algorithms. See also [Ovirt optimizer](http://www.ovirt.org/Features/Optaplanner#Goals) that does VM scheduling.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey De Smet. I got good details from the links